# openpyxl: find highest row for each column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm new to python programming. I've written a script to get data from an api (using python 2.7.8), and now I'd like to add it to an excel spreadsheet where I keep all my data.

In my spreadsheet, each row is one day, but some of the data doesn't become available until up to 30 days later, so some of my columns are not full all the way to the current date. Basically, not all my column lengths are the same.

I'd like to read each column, find the highest row for that column, and then add my data points to the end of that column. If all columns were the same length, this would be simple, but I don't understand how to find the length of each column separately.

I've read through the docs for openpyxl, but I'm new to python and I don't really understand everything. I think the solution will involve something like 'for each column, get the highest row', and then I would append each data point to that column. but I don't understand how to do the 'for each column' part. Finding the length of each column would also work.

thanks in advance

Edit: I came up with a work around: I know the relative length of the columns so I subtracted that from the number for the last row:

```
last_row = ws.get_highest_row() + 1
col_num = 1
dataRow_length = len(dataRow)
row_offset = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 14, 28, 1, 2, 3, 7, 14, 28]

for i in range(0, dataRow_length - 1):
    ws.cell(row=(last_row - row_offset[col_num - 1]), column=col_num).value = dataRow[i]
    col_num = col_num + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate over the rows of a worksheet you can always find the length of a row. That should be sufficient for your purposes. If not, please supply some of your code so it's clearer as to what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for replying Charlie. I was trying to find the length of each column, not row. I couldn't figure out how to do that so I used a work around. I know the relative length of all the columns, so I created a 'row offset' list and subtracted the length of the offset from the last row of the column:

Comment: Worksheets do have a `.columns` property which return all columns in series.